# I cannot read more than a 49 structs array from a file

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

I've got this code. When I compile and execute this, no error is displayed, but, since the 50th element until the last one, the values are out of the interval of rand() (which is, i think, from 0 to 32767). It was quite unexpected, because the program continues without showing any writing-error message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

using namespace std;

struct num {
    int val;
};

int main() {
    FILE *f, *g;
    num data[MAX];

    f = fopen("file1.txt", "w");
    if(f == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        exit(0);
    } else {
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            data[i].val = rand();
        }
        fwrite(data, sizeof(num), MAX, f);
        if(ferror(f)) {
            exit(0);
        }
        fclose(f);
    }

    num data1[MAX];
    g = fopen("file1.txt", "r");

    if(g == NULL) {
        exit(0);
    } else {
        fread(data1, sizeof(num), MAX, g);
        if(ferror(g)) {
            printf("Error\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        fclose(g);

        for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
            printf("val %d : %d\n", i+1, data1[i].val );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The range of `rand` is `0` to `RAND_MAX`, which may or may not be 32767. You should check what it is.

Comment: You seem to be using a hybrid C/C++ scheme here, I would recommend picking one and sticking with it. Also, what happens when you print out `RAND_MAX`? It isn't always 32767, so your code may be performing exactly as specified.

Comment: How should this programme give a writing-error message?

Comment: "which is, i think, from 0 to 32767" - its certainly zero-to-*something*. `std::cout << RAND_MAX << '\n';` at the beginning of your program will squelch any uncertainty you may be harboring. The better question is, if you're looking for a uniform random distribution from *something-to-something-else*, why aren't you using [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and all its yummy goodness, in particular [`std::uniform_int_distribution<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution). And why is this tagged `[c]` ? It clearly has C++ artifacts.

Comment: I ran your code and nothing seems strange about the output, other than it is always the same.  You need to seed rand(), the most common way being to include time.h and call ```srand( time(0) )``` as the first line of ```main```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think issue with the file opening mode, you have chosen `text` mode which is system dependent, change it to `binary` mode and everything would work as **expected**.

**Text mode** is depending on the **environment** where the   application runs, some **special character** conversion may occur in **different input/output text according to a system-specific text** . Although on same environments no conversions will occur for **binary file mode**. **Binary mode** save and read your data without any conversion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with your code.

Add the following at the end of `main` to check any mismatched values.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i )
{
   if ( data[i].val != data1[i].val )
   {
      printf("The %d-th value does not match after reading from file.\n", i);
   }
}
```

Comment: I ran my code and, from the 49th value, I got mismatched values.

Comment: @JafethDíaz, I don't see that behavior on my machine. You could try using the binary mode, `"wb"` and `"rb"`, to open the files. Maybe that will make a difference.

Comment: That's what i did and there was not any problem. I've been reading about differences between binary and text mode to open/write a file. I got that, when accessing a file by the text mode, a character conversion (that may differ from an environment to another) is implicated, which exactly doesn't happen when using the binary mode. How could that characters conversion affect what my code try to write?

Comment: @JafethDíaz, that is platform specific behavior that I don't know how to explain.